# Using whole stack memory

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

Hello I heard that in c++ stack memory is being used  for "normal" variables. How do I make stack full? I tried to use ton of arrays but it didnt help. How big is stack and where is it located?

Comment: Just declare a large c-array inside `main` that is larger than the typical stack size of 1MB.  Post your code here if you have problems.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Don't forget to mention what the real problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: @RichardCritten You are more likely to break stack frame with a large array rather than the stack itself. Subtly different issue (result is likely the same). A mediumly large object and a bit of recursion will quickly blow up the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hello I heard that in c++ stack memory is being used for "normal" variables.

Local (automatic) variables declared in a function or main are allocated memory mostly on stack (or register) and are deallocated when the execution is done.

> How do I make stack full? I tried to use ton of arrays but it didnt help.

Using ton of arrays, many recursive calls, parameter passing large structs that contain ton of arrays are ways. Another way might also be to reduce stack size: -Wl,--stack,number (for gcc)

> How big is stack and where is it located?

It depends on platform, operating system so on. Standard does not determine any stack size. Its location is determined by OS before the program starts. OS allocates a memory for stack from virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language doesn't specify such thing as "stack". It is an implementation detail, and as such it doesn't make sense deliberating about unless we are discussing a particular implementation of C++.

But yes, in a typical C++ implementation, automatic variables are stored on the execution stack.

> How do I make stack full?

Step 1: Use a language implementation that has limited stack size. This is quite common.

Step 2: Create an automatic variable that exceeds the limit. Or nest too many non-tail-recursive function calls. If you're lucky, the program may crash.

You wouldn't want stack to be exhausted in production use.

> How big is stack

Depends on language implementation. It may even be configurable. The default is one to a few megabytes on common desktop/server systems. Less on embedded systems.

> and where is it located?

Somewhere in memory where the language implementation has chosen.

---

The most important thing to take out of this is that the memory available for automatic variables is typically limited. As such:

- Don't use large automatic variables.
- Don't use recursion when asymptotic growth of depth is linear or worse.
- Don't let user input affect the amount or size of automatic variables or depth of recursion without constraint.

Comment: `The C++ language doesn't specify such thing as "stack".` - incorrect in a very technical way. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack ;)

Comment: In a less tongue-in-the-cheek, it is usually not the C++ implementation which deals with stacks. It is usually OS.

Comment: @SergeyA (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

Comment: @SergeyA I count the OS as part of the whole language implementation deal.

Comment: I am not well versed in modern meaning of smiles, (true!), so I can't appreciate your comment. As for distinguishing OS vs language implementation, I find it useful. But I am not forcing my opinion.

Comment: The calling conventions, i.e. how calls are made is partially defined by the OS, partially by the language. Within a compiled piece of code, the compiler can do what it wants as long as it is not trying to call into system libraries or do kernel calls. The sad fact, that especially on Unix like systems, the OS assumes, that "C" defines the ABI blurs the picture, depending on how you think about it. And the Stack is involved in typical calling conventions.